# cakePHP , cant connect to database , XAMPP on windows

Tags: php, database, cakephp

Im recieving the error...

"Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.
Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created."

Ive tried everything Ive read on google,

`extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` is there in php.ini and not commented out...
I also changed the host to whats seen below instead of `localhost`
Ive added that port, it doesnt make a difference.
I have double checked the username and password and db name.

Am I missing anything really obvious?

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
     'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'login' => 'cakeshop',
    'password' => 'connect',
    'database' => 'cakeshop',
    'prefix' => '',
    'port' => '/tmp/mysql.sock'
    //'encoding' => 'utf8'
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'login' => 'cakeshop',
    'password' => 'connect',
    'database' => 'cakeshop',
    'prefix' => '',
    'port' => '/tmp/mysql.sock'
    //'encoding' => 'utf8'
);
}
```

Comment: I assume you've been through all the regular checks? The db is running? You can connect to it from other places/apps etc? The port is correct?

Comment: `'port' => '/tmp/mysql.sock'` is incorrect, you should leave it blank for default for set it to `'port' => '3306'`. Can you connect to MySQL by a sample pure php code(without framework)? or can you connect to mysql via phpmyadmin?